# Pandas pivot_table issues FutureWarning about inferring datetime64 when using margins on dataset with date type

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, pivot-table

When creating a pivot table that includes a date field in the index I get a `FutureWarning` error:

```
<ipython-input-22-330e19e65ef9>:1: FutureWarning: Inferring datetime64[ns] from 
data containing strings is deprecated and will be removed in a future version. 
To retain the old behavior explicitly pass Series(data, dtype={value.dtype})
  pivot_report = pd.pivot_table(
```

Here's the code that triggers it:

```
pivot_report = pd.pivot_table(
    data.loc[(data["year"] == year_to_report)], 
    index = ["Category", "Subcategory", "date"], 
    values = [ "amount"], 
    aggfunc = [np.sum], 
    margins = True)
pivot_report
```

The data was read from csv with explicit types, and the `date` field appears to have been correctly converted to `datetime64` before it hits the `pivot_table` call, so I'm not clear why it is complaining about type inference.

```
data['date']
0       2021-09-10
1       2021-09-08
2       2021-09-08
3       2021-09-08
4       2021-09-08
           ...    
37299   2008-07-31
37300   2008-07-31
37301   2008-07-31
37302   2008-07-31
37303   2008-07-31
Name: date, Length: 37304, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

However I note that while the `margins` parameter adds an `All` row at the bottom as expected, showing the grand total for the `amount` field, it also shows what looks like a `NaT` total for the `date` field.

```
                                                       sum
                                                    amount
Category         Subcategory        date                  
Auto & Transport Advertising        2021-01-01        0.00
                                    2021-01-02        0.00
                                    2021-01-03        0.00
                                    2021-01-04        0.00
                                    2021-01-05        0.00
...                                                    ...
Vacation         Withdrawal         2021-09-06        0.00
                                    2021-09-07        0.00
                                    2021-09-08        0.00
                                    2021-09-10        0.00
All                                 NaT             134.31

[928450 rows x 1 columns]
```

Is this expected? Why would `margins` be trying to provide totals for a date field? And would this explain the type inference `FutureWarning` message?

Comment: i think the `margins` implementation for `MultiIndex` is just a bit buggy, e.g. not your exact issue but seems related https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/29834

Comment: Filed a bug on this: https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/43574. Will follow up here if the issue is confirmed as a bug a/o resolved (fixed or workaround)